# session data is not retrieved in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, session-variables

I have created the internet application ASP.NET MVC Using RAZOR.

I have written in `Index.cshtml` as:

```
@Session["my"]="Hello".
```

and I have written in `AboutUs.cshtml` as:

```
@Session["my"]
```

Still now I can't get the value from  `AboutUs.cshtml` .
Instead of it in `Index.cshtml` it shows:

> ="Hello"

Comment: I know it's not the point but you should consider using session variables at all.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@Session["my"]="Hello";` with  `@{ Session["my"] = "Hello"; }`.

Note the addition of curly brackets.